# How to translate and rotate a text drawing in OpenGl by keyboard

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have a text written using OpenGl in the primitive way, how can I do transilation, rotation and scaling on the whole block of text so that each of these operations is done by pressing one of the keyboard keys?

this is my code referring to the text:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/Gl.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

using namespace std;
void myInit(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glLineWidth(5.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 1000.0, 0.0, 600.0);
}

float xposition = 100, Yposition = 50;

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(xposition, 100);
        glVertex2f(Yposition, 100);
        glVertex2f(Yposition , 50);
        glVertex2f(xposition, 50);
    glEnd();
    //The text I want to translate, rotate and scale
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); // S
        glVertex2i(270, 600);
        glVertex2i(200, 600);
        glVertex2i(280, 400);
        glVertex2i(200, 400);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES); //A
        glVertex2i(300, 400);
        glVertex2i(350, 600);
        glVertex2i(400, 400);
        glVertex2i(350, 600);
        glVertex2i(320, 490);
        glVertex2i(380, 490);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES); //F
        glVertex2i(420, 600);
        glVertex2i(420, 400);
        glVertex2i(420, 600);
        glVertex2i(480, 600);
        glVertex2i(420, 490);
        glVertex2i(470, 490);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES); //I
        glVertex2i(500, 600);
        glVertex2i(560, 600);
        glVertex2i(500, 400);
        glVertex2i(560, 400);
        glVertex2i(530, 600);
        glVertex2i(530, 400);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES); //A
        glVertex2i(580, 400);
        glVertex2i(630, 600);
        glVertex2i(680, 400);
        glVertex2i(630, 600);
        glVertex2i(600, 490);
        glVertex2i(660, 490);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES); //H
        glVertex2i(700, 400);
        glVertex2i(700, 600);
        glVertex2i(780, 400);
        glVertex2i(780, 600);
        glVertex2i(700, 490);
        glVertex2i(780, 490);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); // 2
        glVertex2i(300, 300);
        glVertex2i(330, 300);
        glVertex2i(300, 220);
        glVertex2i(330, 220);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); // 0
        glVertex2i(350, 270);
        glVertex2i(370, 270);
        glVertex2i(370, 230);
        glVertex2i(350, 230);
        glVertex2i(350, 270);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);  //1
        glVertex2i(390, 300);
        glVertex2i(390, 220);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); //6
        glVertex2i(440, 300);
        glVertex2i(410, 300);
        glVertex2i(410, 220);
        glVertex2i(440, 220);
        glVertex2i(440, 270);
        glVertex2i(410, 270);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); // 0
        glVertex2i(460, 270);
        glVertex2i(480, 270);
        glVertex2i(480, 230);
        glVertex2i(460, 230);
        glVertex2i(460, 270);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); //6
        glVertex2i(525, 300);
        glVertex2i(495, 300);
        glVertex2i(495, 220);
        glVertex2i(525, 220);
        glVertex2i(525, 270);
        glVertex2i(495, 270);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); // 7
        glVertex2i(545, 300);
        glVertex2i(575, 300);
        glVertex2i(545, 220);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); //9
        glVertex2i(625, 240);
        glVertex2i(595, 240);
        glVertex2i(595, 300);
        glVertex2i(625, 300);
        glVertex2i(625, 220);
        glVertex2i(595, 220);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); // 0
        glVertex2i(645, 270);
        glVertex2i(665, 270);
        glVertex2i(665, 230);
        glVertex2i(645, 230);
        glVertex2i(645, 270);
    glEnd();
// The end of my text
    
glFlush();
}
void timer(int)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(3000 / 60, timer, 0);
    if (xposition < 200 && Yposition<150);
    xposition += 10;
    Yposition += 10;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("PROGRAM TO DEMONSTRATE COLOR AND GL_LINES");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);

    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are looking for what is so called a ```Transformation Matrix``` that represents these values.

Have a look at this excellent tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change/set the [`GL_MODELVIEW`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) matrix.
Manipulate the current model view matrix with [`glRoatate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml), [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml) and [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml).
Save and restore the matrix on the matrix stack with [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml).

For example:

```cpp
float scale = 0.3f;
float angle = 0.0f;

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw object
    // [...]

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(500.0f, 400.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    angle += 3.0;
    glScalef(scale, scale, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-500.0f, -400.0f, 0.0f);

    // draw text
    // [...]
    
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
}
```

[image]